# What can you do with 100 dollars in relation to investing and raising a business?

Tags: investing, business, financing

I am really curious if it's still possible to start with a low amount of money as I've heard a lot of success stories but wasn't quite certain if it's true or fake. Is it possible to raise a business with just 100 dollars? For example let's say if you buy some old computer parts, assemble them and resell for more money? is it realistic? How long will it take? What kind of steps are necessary to make something big out of it?
EDIT:
*Now I'm gonna revert to the core of the question, what is in the initial phase a stable business model considering low amount of money ?*

Comment: Yeah I was thinking there is also money necessary to promote things, also taxes and marketing have to be considered to make a big plus

Comment: But it's still possible to use Linux which is for free

Comment: Why spend $100 at all? Become a programmer or a consultant or an artist or one of any other job that can be done with what you likely already own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> let's say if you buy some old computer parts, assemble them and resell for more money?

What's the question?

> is it realistic?

Sure.  People sell refurbished computers **all the time**.

> How long will it take?

That's completely unanswerable by anyone, since it depends on your motivation, work ethic, intelligence, location, willingness to think outside the box (at for example marketing and sourcing products), etc.

> What kind of steps are necessary to make something big out of it?

That's also something we can't answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are many rags to riches stories about starving entrepreneurs who went on to become multi-millionaires/billionaires after achieving success (Wozniak and Jobs with Apple, Mark Cuban and Broadcast.com, etc.).  So while it is possible to start with $100 and become wealthy, the odds of it happening are very slim.

Comment: What is considerable amount of money to start a small business?

Comment: A considerable sum of money is any amount that is greater than you have or can raise easily.